# Insert Record and Retrieve Record from database (null pointer exception)

Tags: java, database-design, user-interface, nullpointerexception

When i try to insert record or retrieve record from database, nullpointerexception occur
this is my Maintain Member Control class

```
    package control;
    import da.MemberDa;
    import domain.Member;

    public class MaintainMemberControl {
    private MemberDa memberDa;


    public MaintainMemberControl(){
    memberDa = new MemberDa();
    }

    public void InsertRecord(String studentID, String name, String membership, String      danceStyle, String gender, String faculty, String programme, String yearOfStudy, String dateJoined, String contactNumber,String email){
       memberDa.InsertRecord(studentID, name, membership, danceStyle, gender, faculty, programme, yearOfStudy, dateJoined, contactNumber,email);
     }
    public Member selectRecord(String studentID) {
    return memberDa.getRecord(studentID);
     }

     }
```

MemberDa.java this is my memberDa java class

```
    package da;

    import domain.Member;
    import java.sql.*;
    import java.util.logging.Level;
    import java.util.logging.Logger;
    import javax.swing.*;

    public class MemberDa {

    private String HOST = "jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/GoogleDinosaur";
    private String USERNAME = "GoogleDinosaur";
    private String PASSWORD = "123456";
    private String TABLENAME = "members";

    private Connection conn;
    private PreparedStatement stmt;




    public MemberDa(){
        createConnection();
    }

    private void createConnection(){
        try{
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(HOST, USERNAME, PASSWORD);

    } catch(SQLException ex){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex.getMessage(), "ERROR", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }
    }

  public Member getRecord(String studentID) {
    String queryStr = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLENAME + " WHERE studentID = ?";
    Member member = null;
    try {
        stmt = conn.prepareStatement(queryStr);
        stmt.setString(1, studentID);
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();

        if (rs.next()) {
            member = new Member(studentID, rs.getString("Name"), rs.getString("membership"),rs.getString("dancestyle"),rs.getString("gender"),rs.getString("faculty"),rs.getString("programme"),rs.getString("yearofstudy"),rs.getString("datajoined"),rs.getString("contactnumber"),rs.getString("email"));
        }
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex.getMessage(), "ERROR", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }
    return member;
}

public void InsertRecord(String studentID, String name, String membership, String danceStyle, String gender, String faculty, String programme, String yearOfStudy, String dateJoined, String contactNumber,String email) {
    String queryStr = "INSERT INTO " + TABLENAME + " VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
    Member member = null;
    try {

    stmt = conn.prepareStatement(queryStr);
    stmt.setString(1,studentID);
    stmt.setString(2,name);
    stmt.setString(3,membership);
    stmt.setString(4,danceStyle);
    stmt.setString(5,gender);
    stmt.setString(6,faculty);
    stmt.setString(7,programme);
    stmt.setString(8,yearOfStudy);
    stmt.setString(9,dateJoined);
    stmt.setString(10,contactNumber);
    stmt.setString(11,email);

    stmt.executeUpdate();
    conn.close();
    } catch (SQLException | NumberFormatException ex) {

    }




}

 public static void main(String[] args) {

    MemberDa memberDa = new MemberDa();
}
}
```

MemberTab_redo.java

```
jbSubmit.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            String rbGender= null;

            int prompt = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Insert new member record? ", "Warning", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION,JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

            if (e.getSource() == jbSubmit) {
                if (jrbMale.isSelected()) {
                    rbGender = "Male";
                } else if (jrbFemale.isSelected()) {
                    rbGender = "Female";
                }
            }
            if(prompt == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION){
            memberContr.InsertRecord(jtfStudentID.getText(),jtfName.getText(), (String)jcbMembership.getSelectedItem(), (String)jcbDanceStyle.getSelectedItem(),rbGender,(String) jcbFaculty.getSelectedItem(), jtfProgramme.getText(),(String)jcbYearOfStudy.getSelectedItem(),jtfDateJoined.getText(),jtfContactNumber.getText(),jtfEmail.getText());

            } 
            }
    });
```

When submit button clicked, null pointer exception error everytime.

**From OP comments:**

Below are the errors,

```
line 313 is InsertRecord statement Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at ui.MemberTab_redo$2.actionPerformed(MemberTab_redo.java:313) 
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018) 
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341) 
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402) 
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259) 
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.jav‌​a:252)
```

this line:

```
memberContr.InsertRecord(jtfStudentID.getText(),jtfName.getText(), (String)jcbMembership.getSelectedItem(), (String)jcbDanceStyle.getSelectedItem(),rbGender,(String) jcbFaculty.getSelectedItem(), jtfProgramme.getText(),(String)jcbYearOfStudy.getSelectedItem(),jtfDateJoined.ge‌​tText(),jtfContactNumber.getText(),jtfEmail.getText());
```

Comment: Where is the NPE? Can you include the full error and stack trace?

Comment: Below are the error, line 313 is InsertRecord statement

Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at ui.MemberTab_redo$2.actionPerformed(MemberTab_redo.java:313)
 at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
 at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
 at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
 at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
 at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)

Comment: Which line of `MemberTab_redo` does 313 point to?

Comment: This line >

memberContr.InsertRecord(jtfStudentID.getText(),jtfName.getText(), (String)jcbMembership.getSelectedItem(), (String)jcbDanceStyle.getSelectedItem(),rbGender,(String) jcbFaculty.getSelectedItem(), jtfProgramme.getText(),(String)jcbYearOfStudy.getSelectedItem(),jtfDateJoined.getText(),jtfContactNumber.getText(),jtfEmail.getText());

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The NPE points to the `InsertRecord` line which means one (or more) of the values passed to the method is `NULL`. You'll need to review the code or run some debug to find out which. `jtfStudentID`, `jcbMembership`, etc

Comment: I replace the code to this :  memberContr.InsertRecord("1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11"); , to test again, NPE still occurs

Comment: Then maybe `memberContr` is what's `NULL`

Comment: I don't see anything in `actionPerformed` that sets `memberContr` to anything. Where is it coming from? I can't see the whole class - is it a class member? What ever is responsible for setting it, is allowing to be null.

Comment: yes, i have a member class with all variables private, does it effect it ? but insert Record into database seem didn't interact with the member class

Comment: i can't help without really seeing the class. You need to step through your process and find out at which point it becomes null. If it's not null in other methods, then what's the difference?